# Music software with human voice as the tone

Tags: open-source, music, audio, music-production

Think of it like this, a piano software, in which when Do-Re-Mi etc is played, instead of playing the normal piano tone, it will play the same tone with human voice (as if someone is just practicing their Do-Re-Mi). Is there any software like this?

If the software can handle custom [soundfonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont), then it would be much better.

Free and/or open-source preferred.

Comment: What does it need to interface with? Do you want to trigger from a keyboard (or other instrument), or enter music notation (or perhaps piano roll) to compose, or control via a software API? This is the sort of thing available as a sound-source module or plugin for composition/performance software. You have a good chance of finding what you want in context of other music software, and not stand-alone.

Comment: For (non-free, in fact very expensive) example: http://www.soundsonline.com/Symphonic-Choirs - pretty impressive though!

Comment: @NeilSlater I was thinking of using the computer keyboard for playing the tones. Symphonic-Choirs looks great, but I'm not too sure if it fits the purpose before actually using it. Anyways, check out the other idea I added in the question :)

Comment: For the data part I asked here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3529

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks :D I got a pretty good alternative for that by the way. Choir sound-fonts do the job. But I am still to find a a piano software that would allow using custom sound-fonts. See this: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/piano-software-with-external-sound-font

Comment: "Choir sound-fonts" What is it? Where can I download them? Could you please post that as an answer to my question there? Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I answered your question there. But it is a bit off-topic there, so it may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to use human voice "ooh" and "ahh" sounds in Rosegarden using the FluidR3_GM2-2.sf2 soundfont.  This (for me) is under Arch 64 bit as a virualbox guest using Timidity as the midi daemon under ALSA.  All of this is open source and the soundfont is free with no royalties.

This will satisfy the part of your question "instead of playing the normal piano tone, it will play the same tone with human voice".  I'm not clear if this is what you are looking for or if you are specifically looking for "do-re-mi".

**Links:**

Rosegarden: http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/

Arch Timidity Wiki page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/timidity

The Arch Timidity wiki page details how to setup Timidity as a daemon / user service and should be distribution neutral (though some distributions organize /etc differently than others).  More straight forward than the way I used to use Jack.  The first time you use Rosegarden you *might* need to specify use of timidity through Studio...Manage MIDI Devices.

Comment: including a link would be good ;)

Comment: I can add a link to Rosegarden when I'm on laptop with wifi later.  (Traveling now.)  Most :Rosegarden references mention jack as the midi daemon.  I have used jack in the past and it was painful and didn't play well with other audio programs.  I strongly suggest using timidity for midi playback with Rosegarden over jack for casual use.  A studio environment might be different.  TheArch wiki was very helpful to me (and would likely be useful for any distro) though I referenced several topics there.

Comment: This setup is also now working with Arch as bare metal on my laptop.  Please let me know if there is anything else deserving of a link.  I hope this helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest having a few words with any of:

1. Local Choir Master
2. Local (School) Music Teacher
3. Local Choral Society

to see if you can record a selection of such scales, (in different voices), be sure to get a written agreement on the intended use but I am sure that if you like the idea of such a project they will be very helpful especially if you are planning to open source the results.

Comment: Thanks, but it's really hard for me to get in touch with local musicians due to some problems. That's why I am looking for some tones already available for download. Thanks anyway :)